# Attributing new values to a subset of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I'm using the following line of code to change the value of anything that contains 'GLC' to only 'GLC' for a subset of a pandas DataFrame.

```
xx.loc[xx['Brand'] == 'MERCEDES','Model'][xx[xx['Brand'] == 'MERCEDES']['Model'].str.contains('GLC',case=False)] = 'GLC'
```

As I checked the output for that subset I can see that nothing has change.

```
443         GLC 300
444         GLC 220
445      GLC 43 AMG
446         GLC 300
447         GLC 220
            ...
```

Have been spending way too much time trying to figure out why and any help would be really appreciated at this point. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain both masks by `&` for bitwise `AND`, solution is:

```
xx.loc[(xx['Brand'] == 'MERCEDES') & xx['Model'].str.contains('GLC',case=False),'Model'] = 'GLC'
```